# How to stop setTimeout on success?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, settimeout, cleartimeout

In the `beforeSend` section I have added a `setTimeout`. If ajax takes more than 20 seconds a timeout message appears. If ajax reach success before 20 seconds the `setTimeout` is still running and the timeout message appears.

How do I prevent the timeout message appearing if ajax completes in less than 20 seconds?

form

```
<?= $form->field($relasi, 'npsn')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'npsn', 'onkeyup' => 'sendFirstCategory(this.value)', 'autocomplete' => 'off'])->label(false); ?>
```

JavaScript

```
function sendFirstCategory(npsn)
{
    var test = npsn;
    var timeoutvar = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('keranjang/isi-data-ajax') ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { test: test },
        beforeSend:function()
        {  
            $('#hokya').show();
            $('#hokya').html('<img src="../img/Preloader_1.gif" alt="Loading..." />');

            var a = "";

            $('form [id=nm_sekolah]').val(a);
            $('form [id=email]').val(a);
            $('form [id=telp]').val(a);
            $('form [id=alamat]').val(a);
            $('form [id=penanggung_jawab]').val(a);

            timeoutvar = setTimeout(function() { 
                $("#hokya").hide(); 
                $('#login-modal').modal('show');
                $('form [id=nm_sekolah]').val(a);
                $('form [id=email]').val(a);
                $('form [id=telp]').val(a);
                $('form [id=alamat]').val(a);
                $('form [id=penanggung_jawab]').val(a);
            }, 20000);
        },
        success: function(data)
        {

            clearTimeout(timeoutvar);
            var o = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(o, function(key, value){
                $('form [id=' + key + ']').val(value);
            });

            $('#hokya').hide();
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `clearTimeout(timeout)`?

Comment: *"if [success] i declare clearTimeout there, the setTimeout is still running"* - Please [edit] your question to show the code that doesn't work, where you had `clearTimeout()` in your success handler. And as an aside, why are you using selectors like `'form [id=nm_sekolah]'`? Why not just `'#nm_sekolah'`?

Comment: oops, my bad. i've edit it. `'form [id=nm_sekolah]'` just worked fine.. @nnnnnn

Comment: my bad, that should my code look like, there's a clearTimeout on success selectors, i have edit it @NewToJS

Comment: put `timeoutvar` outside function

Comment: @NewbeeDev - That's not necessary, it is already declared at a point that is in scope for both the `beforeSend` and `success` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a error callback function,and check whether the status is timeout.of course,you need to set timeout:20 too.

ajax api from jquery:

error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

```
function sendFirstCategory(npsn){
var test = npsn;
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('keranjang/isi-data-ajax') ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { test: test },
    beforeSend:function()
    {  
        $('#hokya').show();
        $('#hokya').html('<img src="../img/Preloader_1.gif" alt="Loading..." />');

        var a = "";

        $('form [id=nm_sekolah]').val(a);
        $('form [id=email]').val(a);
        $('form [id=telp]').val(a);
        $('form [id=alamat]').val(a);
        $('form [id=penanggung_jawab]').val(a);
    },
    timeout:200000,
    success: function(data)
    {
        var o = $.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(o, function(key, value){
            $('form [id=' + key + ']').val(value);
        });

        $('#hokya').hide();
    },
    error:function(jqXHR,textStatus) 
    {
        if (textStatus=='timeout') {
            var a = "";
            $("#hokya").hide(); 
            $('#login-modal').modal('show');
            $('form [id=nm_sekolah]').val(a);
            $('form [id=email]').val(a);
            $('form [id=telp]').val(a);
            $('form [id=alamat]').val(a);
            $('form [id=penanggung_jawab]').val(a);
        }
    }
```

});
}

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeout = setTimeout(...)` statement assigns the timeout id to a global variable called `timeout`. Your `clearTimeout(timeoutvar);` uses a *different* variable, `timeoutvar`.

Change `timeout` to `timeoutvar`.

Comment: I've edit it in my code, and still give me same result